USB Hub Integration on Raspberry Pi CM4 Daughterboard: Seeking Advice and Potential Issues
I am currently designing a daughterboard for a Raspberry Pi CM4, and I am considering the best way to integrate a USB hub. My current idea is to use a USB2514B hub chip directly on the daughterboard. The plan is to connect the USB modules internally on the daughterboard, and only link the hub output to the mainboard (and thus to the CM4) through a single USB port.
I wonder if this approach is viable in terms of signal integrity and overall reliability. I also have only one shot for prototyping, so I would appreciate knowing if any of you have done something similar and what problems you may have encountered. Any constructive criticism is very welcome.
